# Url rewrite and Google crawling ajax content

Tags: ajax, web-crawler, googlebot

I have a quick question for web professionals.
Supposing I Url-rewrite www.example.com/member.php?id=1 to www.example.com/member/member-name-1
and on member.php I have:

**member.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function UpdateMember()
{
   var member_id = '<?php echo $_GET['id']?>';
   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'update_member.php',
   data: {'member_id': member_id},
   success: function(response)
   {
     var d = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
     $('#member-details').empty();
     $('#member-details').append(d.data);   
   }
  });
}
</head>
<body>
<div id="#member-details"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**update_member.php**

```
<?php
    $respose = "";
    if($_POST['id']==1)
       $respose = "Content test";
    echo json_encode(array('data'=>$respose));     
?>
```

Will Google index the "Content test"? (I believe not) 
How can I make it to do so? (I was reading Google's AJAX crawling starter guide, but I'm not sure how that applies to this case: should I change the URL from www.example.com/member/member-name-1 to www.example.com/member/member-name-1#!id=1 ?? Will that work?).
Thanks!!!